# Problem with MSVC Runtime Dependencies

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I have built several DLL's that use the MSVCRT.lib, which have all been successfully created however in Dependency Walker there are 5 missing dependencies, 1 of which is mine and is nothing to worry about.

The other 4 dependencies are
MSVCP90.dll
MSVCR90.dll
Delayed load of GPSVC.DLL
Delayed load of IESHIMS.DLL

I read that IESHIMS.DLL is nothing to worry about.  How can I specify to my DLL to not include  GPSVC.DLL if it is not needed.  Is there a linker option for it.

Note:  I am doing this compile by command line from a maven script.

Answer (score 0):

GPSVC.DLL is the Group Policy client. It's delay loaded, so it will be loaded only when used. If you are not using Group Policy API, you can just ignore it.

Comment: Don't you love Microsoft's naming of DLL's?

Comment: The short DLL name is historical. I'm told microsoft had a policy to make all names fit in a 8.3 filesystem (long ago CD's had this restricion).

Comment: There is only a 32 bit version of GPSVC.DLL, will this cause problems when its loaded from a 64bit DLL.  I would imagine so, but this library doesn't exist in the SysWOW64 directory...

Comment: Are you using Group Policy API? If you don't, the DLL will never be loaded. It's shown as a dependency because the dependency walker is not perfect. It makes mistakes from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

With windows the msvc runtimes are usually NOT stored in your application directory. Hence why dependency walker will show them as missing. There may be an option in depends to point to the directory where they are located, but I think that most likely not necassary.